# Related Rate- cost revenue and profit. need help solving

Tags: calculus

A company that manufactures sport supplements calculates that its costs and revenue can be modeled by the equations

$$C= 125000 + 0.75 x$$ and $$R = 250 x - \frac{1}{10}{x^2}$$

where $x$ is the number of units of sport supplements produced in $1$ week. Production during one particular week is $1000$ units and is increasing at a rate of $150$ units per week. Find the rates at which the a) cost, b) revenue, and c) profit are changing.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried plugging in $x=1000$ and $x=1150?$  That would give you a check of your answer.  Can you take the derivatives of $C,R$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: im confused how to tackle this question. I know i need to differentiate in respect to t but I  think im doing it wrong. 

im getting dy/dt = 0.75(dx/dt)  ?

Comment: I really want to help.  So, please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C=125,000 + 0.75x$ and $R=250x-\frac1{10}x^2$.  We are given that $x=1,000$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}=150$ per week.

Using the chain rule, $\frac{dC}{dt}=\frac{dC}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dR}{dt}=\frac{dR}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}$.

Thus,

$$\frac{dC}{dt}=0.75 \frac{dx}{dt}=0.75 \times 150$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dR}{dt}&=\left(250-\frac15 x\right)\frac{dx}{dt}\\
&=\left(250-\frac15 (1000)\right) \times 150
\end{align}$$

Since profit is simple revenue minus cost, the rate of change in profit is simply the difference between the rate of change of revenue and the rate of change of cost.

Comment: thank you very much. So i got 112.5 for the Cost and 7500 for the Revenue. 


Do I simply 7500-112.5 to find the profit  now?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!  And you are correct.  It is that straightforward to find the rate of change in profit.

Comment: awesome! thank you again. I first made a  mistake that x=150 instead of 1000 but now i know my problem now